# How to show the residue of an analytic function's derivative is equal to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

Let $r>0$ . for $f: \Bbb D_r(0)-{0}\mapsto \Bbb C$  analytic function show that $Res(f';0)=0$

we know by residue therom $∫_Cf'(z)dz=2iπRes(f',0)$

What property of analytic functions will we use?
How can I continue? Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean showing the residue of the derivative of an analytic function at zero is equal to zero by your question right?

Comment: @ireallydonknow my mistake. fixed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a closed curve $C$ in $N_0(0,r)$. (I use this notation for the punctured disk centered at $0$) Now since $f$ is analytic on $N_0(0,r)$, we must have $f'$ to be analytic on $N_0(0,r)$ and hence continuous on $N_0(0,r)$. So it follows that

$$\int_C{f'(z)}dz = f(b)-f(a)$$
where a and b are start and end points of $C$.

Now since $C$ is closed, therefore

$$\int_C{f'(z)}dz = 0$$

Now since $f'$ is analytic on $N_0(0,r)$, we have that there is a Laurent Series Expansion of $f'$. Conclude.

Comment: Note that $f$ is only assumed to be analytic on the punctured disc; $f$ and $f'$ may very well have singularities at $z=0$.

Comment: I apologize. I did not see the $-0$ there. I'll do the required edits now.

Comment: start and end points of $C$, not of its image.  That is, for a parametric curve $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb C$, 
$a = \gamma(0)$ and $b = \gamma(1)$.  These might not look like start and end points if you only see the image, because the curve could double back on itself.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, of course. Thank you very much for the corection.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for a curve $C$ starting at $a$ and ending at $b$, $\int_C f'(z)\ dz = f(b) - f(a)$.