# Does it mean $\displaystyle\lim_{z=0}\oint\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{f(z)^n}dz=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

### Source of my question

My question comes from the book "Introduction to Analysis" (by 高木貞治)
 → Chapter  7 "Sequel to Differentiation (Implicit Functions)"
 → Section 85 "Application to analytic functions"

( [The scanned PDF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiYi8.jpg) of relevant pages for some interested)
(P.S. also the last difficulty in the whole book that makes me unwilling to let go)

―The **gist** is to solve the coefficients in the power series form of the inverse function.

---

Below is the English translation of the excerpts from the relevant parts of the book.
$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\dz{\d z}\def\i{\mathrm{i}}\require{cancel}$

> ###### p330
>
> **Theorem 76** Assume in some region $K$ of the complex number plane ($z$ plane),
> $$w = f(z) \tag{1}$$
> is regular, and $w=w_0$ at a point $z=z_0$ in $K$. If $f'(z_0)\neq0$ at $z_0$, then a unique holomorphic inverse function $z=g(w)$ is determined near $w=w_0$.
>
> ###### p332
>
> (1°) In theorem 76, substituting $z,w$ for $z-z_0, w-w_0$ for simplicity, utilizing $f'(0)\neq0$, then in the vicinity of $z=0$, hold
> $$w = f(z) = a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots, \quad a_1\neq0. \tag{8}$$
> Now, since it is known that the inverse function is holomorphic near $w=0$, it can be assumed that
> $$z = b_1 w + b_2 w^2 + \cdots \tag{9}\label{eqn:z to w series}.$$
>
> (2°) In the region of the $z$ plane where the above inverse function is definite, if $C$ is a circle centered at the origin, the coefficient $b_n$ in $\eqref{eqn:z to w series}$ can be written in a simpler form. Now let $z_1$ be a point in $C$ and $w_1=f(z_1)$ and make
> $$I = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint_C \frac{zf'(z)\dz}{f(z)-w_1}, \tag{10}\label{eqn:oint of w1}$$
> then the integrand only has a first-order pole at $z=z_1$ in $C$, hence $I$ is equal to the residue at $z=z_1$, in consequence,
> $$I = \lim_{z\to z_1} \frac{z(z-z_1)f'(z)}{f(z)-w_1} = z_1.$$
> Now at $\eqref{eqn:oint of w1}$, using the uniform convergence of
> $$\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w_1} = \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} \left\{ 1 + \frac{w_1}{f(z)} + \frac{w_1^2}{f(z)^2} + \cdots \right\}$$
> to integrating term by term, $I$ (is also $z_1$) can be expanded to a power series of $w_1$. I.e. in $\eqref{eqn:z to w series}$,
> $$b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint_C \frac{zf'(z)\dz}{f(z)^{n+1}}, \tag{11}\label{eqn:b_n}$$
> or using
> $$\frac{\d}{\dz}\frac{z}{f(z)^n} = \frac{1}{f(z)^n} - \frac{nzf'(z)}{f(z)^{n+1}}, \tag{eq1}$$
> get
> $$nb_n = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint_C \frac{\dz}{f(z)^n}. \tag{eq2}$$
> The right-hand side is exactly the residue of $f(z)^{-n}$ at $z=0$. Therefore
> $$b_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left[ \frac{\d^{n-1}}{\dz^{n-1}} \left(\frac{z}{f(z)}\right)^n \right]_{z=0}. \tag{12}$$
> This is right the value of the coefficient $b_n$ in $\eqref{eqn:z to w series}$ (Lagrange's expansion).

---

### My question

I have a doubt about the possible process for deriving eq2 from ⌞$\eqref{eqn:b_n}$ and eq1⌟ , seems that the combination of those formulas imply
$$\displaystyle\lim_{z=0}\oint\frac{\d}{\dz}\frac{z}{f(z)^n}\dz=0, \tag{eq}\label{eqn:q}$$
but doesn't $\dfrac{\d}{\dz}\dfrac{z}{f(z)^n}$ have a **singularity** at $z=0$? (In that case, how does the value of the formula $\eqref{eqn:q}$ above exactly equal $0$?)

(*End of question*)

I have made some *mindless verification-like* **attempts** in the following ways along my above probably incorrect assertion.
BTW, I checked that $n=0 \iff b_n=0$ by $\eqref{eqn:b_n}$.

1. [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)：
   $\displaystyle \oint f(z)\,\dz=0$
2. [Cauchy's integral formula](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)：
   $\displaystyle f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,\dz$
3. [Residue formula](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles)：
   $\displaystyle \operatorname{Res}(\frac{z}{f(z)^n},0) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z\to0}\frac{\d^{n-1}}{\dz^{n-1}}z^n\frac{z}{f(z)^n}$
4. IBP：
   $\displaystyle \left(\text{let} \oint uv_z\,\dz =\right) \oint \frac{z}{f(z)^n} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\dz$
   and "[unit circle corollary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Discussion)"：
   $\displaystyle \oint \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\dz = \oint \frac{\d f(z)}{f(z)}\left(=\oint\frac{\dz}{z-\kern-.25em\cancelto{0}{a}}=\i\int_0^{2\pi}\d\theta\right)=2\pi\i$

**But**, I (since really have no other ideas so had to recklessly) deliberately ignored two conditional points:
(a) where $z=0$ there is $w=f(z)=0$ so that $\dfrac{z}{w}$ is non-regular, and for $\dfrac{z}{f(z)^n}$, there is also a singularity here (equivalent to $\dfrac{1}{f'(z)\,f(z)^{n- 1}}$ with a pole of order $n-1$);
(b) the convergence rates of the mappings are not necessarily equal, that is, $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z}{w}$ is not necessarily equal to $1$.
So actually all the calculations I've done are applied mechanically and are of course absurdly wrong.

---

---

#### Appendix

##### The original text (Japanese)

> ###### p330
>
> **定理 76** 複素数平面（$z$ 平面）の或る領域 $K$ において
> $$w = f(z) \tag{1}$$
> は正則で，$K$ 内の一点 $z=z_0$ において $w=w_0$ とする．もしも $z_0$ において $f'(z_0)\neq0$ ならば，$w=w_0$ の近傍で正則なる逆函数 $z=g(w)$ が確定する．
>
> ###### p332
>
> (1°) 定理 76 において簡単のために $z-z_0, w-w_0$ に $z,w$ を代用すれば，$f'(0)\neq0$ を用いて，$z=0$ の近傍で
> $$w = f(z) = a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots, \quad(a_1\neq0). \tag{8}$$
> さて $w=0$ の近傍で逆函数が正則であることが知られているから，と置いてよい
> $$z = b_1 w + b_2 w^2 + \cdots \tag{\ref{eqn:z to w series}}.$$
>
> (2°) 上記逆函数が確定である $z$ 平面の領域内において，原点を中心とする円を $C$ とすれば，$\eqref{eqn:z to w series}$ における係数 $b_n$ が見やすい形に書き表わされる．今 $z_1$ を $C$ 内の点とし，また $w_1=f(z_1)$ として
> $$I = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint_C \frac{zf'(z)\dz}{f(z)-w_1} \tag{\ref{eqn:oint of w1}}$$
> と置けば，被積分函数は $C$ 内で $z=z_1$ において一次の極を有するだけだから，$I$ は $z=z_1$ における留数に等しく，従って
> $$I = \lim_{z\to z_1} \frac{z(z-z_1)f'(z)}{f(z)-w_1} = z_1.$$
> さて $\eqref{eqn:oint of w1}$ において
> $$\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w_1} = \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} \left\{ 1 + \frac{w_1}{f(z)} + \frac{w_1^2}{f(z)^2} + \cdots \right\}$$
> の一様収束性を用いて項別積分をすれば，$I$ すなわち $z_1$ が $w_1$ の巾級数に展開される．すなわち $\eqref{eqn:z to w series}$ において
> $$b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint_C \frac{zf'(z)\dz}{f(z)^{n+1}}, \tag{\ref{eqn:b_n}}$$
> または
> $$\frac{\d}{\dz}\frac{z}{f(z)^n} = \frac{1}{f(z)^n} - \frac{nzf'(z)}{f(z)^{n+1}} \tag{eq1}$$
> を用いて
> $$nb_n = \frac{1}{2\pi\i} \oint_C \frac{\dz}{f(z)^n}. \tag{eq2}$$
> 右辺は $z=0$ における $f(z)^{-n}$ の留数である．従って
> $$b_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left[ \frac{\d^{n-1}}{\dz^{n-1}} \left(\frac{z}{f(z)}\right)^n \right]_{z=0}. \tag{12}$$
> これが $\eqref{eqn:z to w series}$ における係数 $b_n$ の値である [Lagrangeの展開]．

Comment: Integrating the *derivative* of an analytic function over a closed curve always gives zero, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/612677/42969

Comment: Adding to @MartinR 's comment. There is no $z$ to take the limit with respect to in the expression you are asking about. That integral is just a number. It happens to be $0$.

Comment: So the derivative of any function must be regular? I don't understand why it's established...

Comment: Although the conclusion is the same, doesn't $\dfrac{z}{f(z)^n}$ have a singularity at $z=0$? And (following the previous comment) so not the *derivative of any analytic* function is unconditionally full-plane analytic right? @MartinR